# Newbie Java Programmer needs help involving for loops

Tags: java, return

I am just trying to create an example program to help me remember how to operate for loops, when I ran it through the `compiler`. The Compiler said `missing return statement`. Where do I add it? 
Here is the code:

```
 public class LoopExample {
     public String bam() {
         for (int i = 0; i <  8; i++) {
             System.out.println(i);
         }
     }
 }
```

**EDIT** 
I received an answer, but now the main says 'cannot find symbol'... here is the code for the main:

```
 public class LoopExampleTestDrive {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         bam looper = new bam();
         System.out.println(looper);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Similar question [JAVA: missing return statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19525594/1761793)

Comment: Please learn to indent your code

Comment: If it is an unrelated problem, raise a new question.  Btw, `bam` is a method, not a class. hence `bam looper = new bam()` does not make sense

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to try to understand how Object Oriented languages work first.

That being said, the main reason why your code doesn't work, is because you try to make an object of the class bam with `new bam()`. This class unfortunately doesn't exist as it is only a method in a class. My solution would look like:

```
public class LoopExample {
     public void bam() {
         for (int i = 0; i <  8; i++) {
             System.out.println(i);
         }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         new LoopExample().bam();
     }
}
```

As I said: try to understand object oriented programming first, before trying to continue programming in Java. It is too essential to be able to write working code.

PS: just to be complete, the best way to write what you want to do, would look as follows.

```
public class LoopExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Surprisingly I managed to fix this myself. I am learning OO programming with a book (Head First Java), I just thought I would attempt to make a program without the book... I kinda cheated with this website though

Comment: @Ethan don't forget to accept the answer that helped you! This helps stackoverflow to stay clean :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of your method. Replace `public String bam()` with `public void bam()`. `void`means that you return  nothing instead of a String as before.

For further information see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm